# LDAP tomcat JNDIRealm

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, ldap

I am using the below server.xml file to configure tomcat to use **JNDIRealm** to connect to **ldap** server.

However I keep getting error :

> Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: localhost:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]

I am nowhere using localhost:389 if you see my connection url used host and 636 port. So what is it causing to connect to localhost:389.

Below is server.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
<GlobalNamingResources>
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
<Service name="Catalina">
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" 
 SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" 
 keystoreFile="keystore_key.jks" keystoreType="JKS" 
 keystorePass="xxxxx" URIEncoding="UTF-8" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" /> 
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">    
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
            connectionURL="ldap://mycomapny.org:636" 
            userSubtree="true"
            userBase="DC=test,DC=win,DC=user,DC=org" 
            userSearch="(&amp;(sAMAccountName={0})(objectcategory=user))"
            userRoleName="memberOf" 
            roleBase="DC=test,DC=win,DC=user,DC=org" 
            roleName="cn"
            roleSearch="(member={0})" 
            roleSubtree="true" 
            roleNested="true"/>
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps">
            <Context docBase="spnego" path="">
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator"
                    storeDelegatedCredential="true" />
            </Context>
        </Host>
</Engine>
</Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: can someone atleast guide me on any guide/steps to setup ldap using JNDIRealm?

Comment: Your URL is mis-spelt.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try specifying ldaps in the connectionURL setting, i.e.
connectionURL="ldaps://mycompany.org:636"

port 389 is for a non-secure connection